# How to create form elements input box , label using javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to know how to create a hidden type input box and labels using javascript by onclick function.

```
$().ready(function() {  
    $("#product").autocomplete("get_completeproducts", {            
        width: 406,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});


<input type="text" value="" name="product" id="product" size="50">
<input type="button" value="Add to List" onclick="addprotolist()" name="select_pro">
```

i am getting the above input box value through ajax auto complete , the user will click on the select box , then what i have to do is , i have to add list them the number of selected phones bellow the input box like

```
<label>Samsung Galaxy Y<label><input type="hidden" value="778" name="pro_id[]">
<label>Samsung Galaxy Y Duos<label><input type="hidden" value="788" name="pro_id[]">
<label>Samsung Galaxy Y Plus<label><input type="hidden" value="728" name="pro_id[]">
.
.
.
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save your list">
```

anybody can provide me how to code this using javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function addprotolist() {
  var str = '<label>'+ var_for_text +'</label><input type="hidden" value="'+ var_for_value +'" name="pro_id[]">';
  $('#yourform').append( str );
}
```

#### Note

If you want to append multiple `input`, `label` etc using loop, don't call append within loop, it will slow down performance. Make a string like above and call `.append()` at last out of loop.

**For example**

```
var str = '';
function addprotolist(inputObj) {

  // a typical example of inputObj may be
  // inputObj = [ {labelText: 'some 1', value: 'val1' }, {labelText: 'some 2', value: 'val2'} ]

  // loop
  for(var i = 0; i < inputObj.length; i++ ) {
    str += '<label>'+ inputObj[i].labelText +'</label><input type="hidden" value="'+ inputObj[i].value +'" name="pro_id[]">';
  }

  // call append outside of loop
  $('#yourform').append( str );
}
```

---

But this way it does not really make sense to use a `label`. You have to connect it to your `input` either by wrapping it or by specifying a `for` attribute pointing to the input's `id`:

```
<!-- Simple label example with for attribute -->  
<input type="radio" name="clickmebutton" id="clickmebutton">
<label for="clickmebutton">Click me</label>  

<!-- or more simply -->  
<label><input type="radio" name="clickmebutton"> Click me</label>
```

from [`label` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: What is a label worth if it is not connected to the input?

Comment: @bažmegakapa I tried to give an example just, waiting for OP's comment

Comment: i tried this example and this works fine for me. i got it now.

Comment: @bažmegakapa thanks Sir, I also tried to give some note to OP, thanks again Sir

Comment: The above notes and example helps me lot. Thanks